# Subscribing to observable of 2 types on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, angular-observable

Sorry about the title, but I could not find a better one.

I'm calling an HTTP API that returns a json object when sending a GET command but it will return 404 if the resource was not found.
I'm using Angular 9 and I'm trying to find an way to output the json object from the service or return an enum value of the received HTTP error on the same Observable.

Please, see some code below:

## device.service.ts

```
getDevice(objectID: number | string): Observable<Device | ResponseStatus> {
    return this.http.get<Device>(`http://localhost:8080/Registration/Device/${objectID}`)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<ResponseStatus> {
    switch (error.status) {
      case 404: {
        return of(ResponseStatus.objectNotFound);
        break;
      }
      case 409: {
        return of(ResponseStatus.objectAlreadyExists);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

I wish to return ResponseStatus to my components, so I can process all the errors the same way.

## device-item-resolver-service.ts

```
export class DeviceItemResolverService implements Resolve<Device> {

  constructor(private ds: DeviceService, private router: Router) { }
  
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Device> | Observable<never> {

    let objectID = route.paramMap.get('objectID');

    return this.ds.getDevice(objectID).pipe(
      take(1),
      mergeMap(
        (item: Device) => {
          if (item) {
            return of(item);
          }
          else {
            this.router.navigate(['/devices']);
            return EMPTY;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Everything apparently is going well. Running the program I can receive the Device but I can't find a way to process the ResponseStatus on the resolver.

Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use `typeof` or `instanceof` as suggested, so I found a great document about advanced types in typescript, follows:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

See below how I solved this issue:

First I defined a user-defined type guard:

```
function isDevice(value: Device | ResponseStatus): value is Device {
      return (value as Device).objectID !== undefined;
    }
```

Then I called this funcion on my original code:

```
return this.ds.getDevice(objectID).pipe(
      take(1),
      mergeMap(
        (item: Device | ResponseStatus) => {
          if (!item) {
            this.router.navigate(['/devices']);
            return EMPTY;
          }
          else if (isDevice(item)) {
            return of(item)
          }
          else {
            switch (item as ResponseStatus) {
              case ResponseStatus.objectNotFound: {
                this.router.navigate(['/devices']);
                return EMPTY;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )
    )        
  }
```

Notice that I need to use the `mergeMap`. `map` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mergeMap` is not needed because `map` should be good enough in this case.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
return this.ds.getDevice(objectID).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(
        (item: Device | ResponseStatus) => {
          // this if statement I think is the culprit.
          // Basically ResponseStatus.objectNotFound is true and it goes here
          // I am not sure if instanceof will work but basically you have to find out 
          // if you're getting Device or ResponseStatus and act accordingly
          if (item instanceof Device) {
            return item;
          }
          else {
            this.router.navigate(['/devices']);
            return null;
          }
        }
      )
    );
```